# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication failed: Error: Not enough credit

Tags: java, email, smtp

sorry for the noob question. but this was working before, then now it is not. i don't understand why.

please see the codes below

we have a smtp server.

it was working properly, but after afew testing it was like that already.

I could ping the smtp server, it is still alive.

```
'
package ph.com.autoemailer.util;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Mailer{
String d_email = "<this is not empty>",
d_password = "<this is not empty>",
d_host = "<this is not empty>",
d_port = "<this is not empty>",
m_to = "<this is not empty>",
//m_to = "<this is not empty>",
m_subject = "Auto-Email Notification: Receipt of Payment Confirmation FAO",
m_text = "Hey, this is the testing email.";
String formatMessage = "";
String dearGreetings;
String sbuGreetings;
String part1Message;
String part2Message;
String part2MessageImg;
String tyMessage;
String sbuMessage;
String noteMessage;
String iNoteMessage;


@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public Mailer(){
        System.out.println("Start Mailer ...... ");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

        try {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            session.setDebug(true);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            dearGreetings = "<this is not empty>";
            sbuGreetings = "<this is not empty>";

            part1Message = "<this is not empty>";

            part2Message = "<this is not empty>";

            part2MessageImg = "<this is not empty>";;
            tyMessage = "Yours truly,<br/><br/><br/>";

            sbuMessage = "<this is not empty>";

            noteMessage = "<this is not empty>";

            iNoteMessage = "<this is not empty>";

            formatMessage = dearGreetings+sbuGreetings+part1Message+part2Message+part2MessageImg+tyMessage+sbuMessage+noteMessage+iNoteMessage;
            m_text = formatMessage;
            msg.setText(m_text);
            msg.setSubject(m_subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(m_to));

            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart); 
            msg.setContent(multipart);

            // creates body part for the attachment

            messageBodyPart.setContent(formatMessage, "text/html");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            String attachFile = "<this is not empty>";
            // read this file into InputStream
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(attachFile);
            byte[] bytesInputStream = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            Date getDateToday = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatDateToday = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            String finishFormatDate = formatDateToday.format(getDateToday);
            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("<this is not empty>"+".pdf"));

            String convertedattachFile = "<this is not empty>"+".pdf";

            DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytesInputStream, "application/pdf");//new FileDataSource(convertedattachFile);

            attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachPart.setFileName(new File(attachFile).getName());
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Email Is Sending...");
        }
    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(d_password, d_password);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Mailer blah = new Mailer();
    }


}
```

here is the error result

```
    Start Mailer ...... 
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.3
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.elasticemail.com", port 2525, isSSL false
220 smtp.elasticemail.com ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.elasticemail.com", port: 2525

EHLO 10.24.51.120
250-smtp.elasticemail.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20971520
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "20971520"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=PLAIN", arg "LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "OK", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 Begin TLS negotiation
EHLO 10.24.51.120
250-smtp.elasticemail.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20971520
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "20971520"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=PLAIN", arg "LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "OK", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication failed: Error: Not enough credit.

Email Is Sending...
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at ph.com.autoemailer.util.Mailer.<init>(Mailer.java:140)
    at ph.com.autoemailer.util.Mailer.main(Mailer.java:173)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is a custom error. Probably the **elasticemail** service is a payd service and you haven't enough credit to send emails.

Check your credit.

Comment: haha!! yeahh,, the client forgot that it has no more credit.. almost lost my mind because of this.. dang.

Comment: If you find this answer useful you can up vote it and flag it has the correct answer (with the green check)